# UITableViewStyleGrouped appears as plain in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

When using the iOS 6 SDK and running my app in the iPhone 5.0 simulator my tableview appears just fine as a grouped style tableview. However when I run my in the iPhone 6.0 simulator it appears as a UITableViewStylePlain tableview.

Any ideas what would cause this strange behavior? I'm not doing anything too crazy in the tableview besides a textview inside a tableview cell.

Comment: can you check the runtime value of the tableview style? maybe the background tableview color is causing the table to look plain when it's grouped...

Comment: The runtime value is plain and it looks plain.

Comment: In my custom init I use [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGroup] then I check it's runtime value on the next line and it's plain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a grouped tableview that is working correctly in iOS6 using the code:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
[tableView setDelegate:self];
```

Are you using the Interface builder to create this grouped tableview or are you creating it programmatically?  There seems to be quite a few issues with iOS6 and previously created interfacebuilder views.

If you are using the IB to create things can you try to re-create the tableview in code (redundant and useless, I know, but it may show what is the problem).

Somewhere in your viewDidLoad() function put

```
    if(tableView)
    {
        [tableView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:tableView];
```

This may be poor coding or cause memory leaks if not using arc, but it would be interesting to see if you get a grouped styling that way.

Comment: I'm not using IB for this view and I'm using a UITableViewController subclass. It must be something with my subclass because if I create a default UITableViewController w/ grouped style it appears grouped.

Comment: Ave you tried initializing your subclass with initWithStyle: and not overloading that function in your subclass?  If you don't overload the function then the superclass function gets called, as though you weren't using your sublcass at all.  I don't now what you are doing in your init, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Tried not overloading init and I still got plain.

Comment: you were right I had a xib hidden away in another group and it was set to plain. Interesting that iOS 5 handles it differently from 6 though.

Comment: @SteveMoser Hey I am having a problem that is very related to what you had. How exactly did you solve it. I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant by "having a xib hidden away" Did you make your tableview with a xib or programmatically? Thanks a lot for the feedback!

Comment: @Joze I alloc, init'd a UITableViewController with a plain style but I had a xib file named the same as my UITableViewController subclass and it was set plain not grouped style.

Answer (score 3):

This code solved the ios6 grouped tableview problem for me:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```